# Passing DOM variables to Reactjs as props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Please forgive me if my question seems ridiculous but I'm new to ReactJs.

I have a react component that reflects the user's sign In status:

```
<AccountStatus iconsize="medium" activate={[true,false,true]}/>
```

[Image 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/644jbulokvrqjdy/Untitled2.png?dl=0)

```
//or using
<AccountStatus iconsize="medium" activate={true}/>
```

[Image 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/210de4ztgfk21sa/Untitled.png?dl=0)

I handle the application logic separately in another (non-react) js file which is loaded alongside other scripts when the page is loaded:

```
<script src="/assets/js/logic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In this last file I handle the user authentication and update the global variables accordingly. I'd like to be able to modify the state of the component based on the changes that occur in these global variables.

```
var user, credential, token;
var providers = {
    facebook.com: true,
    twitter.com: false,
    google.com: true,
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be approaching your requirement in a different directions.

So check for the authentication [here](https://medium.com/the-many/adding-login-and-authentication-sections-to-your-react-or-react-native-app-7767fd251bd1#.j4cg6uf3c). This should be a fairly simple way to authenticate the user.

> In this last file I handle the user authentication and update the global variables accordingly. I'd like to be able to modify the state of the component based on the changes that occur in these global variables.

This statement by you forces me to think you will need to have [redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) for global state management.

I know this will be a tough thing to wrap your mind around, but this would be the right approach!

Comment: @CarlosE. Good luck!

Comment: @CarlosE. If you found the answer useful - upvote and accept it. Will help others when they end up here.

Comment: Hello @Nevin, unfortunately I haven't had much time to get familiar redux since this is more of a personal project, I'm getting around the issue by using Lifecycle methods and loading scripts dynamically, however managing state this way is still a bit tricky, I am sure there must be a better, much simpler and more straightforward way. - regards